# Determine user credentials in shinyapps.io (not Pro)

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a simple app in shinyapps.io and I am bringing in data from a MySQL hosted table successfully.  I would like to only show data that is relevant to the user that is viewing the app and hide data that does not relate to them.  If the user has not logged into shinyapps.io then NULL will be returned and no data will be shown.  From the documentation and search results, it seems like this can be done using session$user but only on Shiny Server Pro.  I don't think this can be done in shinyapps.io, is this correct?  If so, my app has come to a grinding halt as I can't go down the whole Linux / Pro route.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Andy Kipp from RStudio for answering this via Google Groups.
"If you're running on shinyapps.io, and your application is set to private (under Users tab), when a person logs into your application the email address of the person who is logged in will be in session$user. We don't expose anything other then the email address. Again this is for private applications only. Private applications are available in the Standard plan and higher."

Good to know, took me a while to pin this down, thanks Andy.